# Raphael images/shapes are not showing on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having tremendous difficulty trying to figure out why my Raphael images are not showing on my HTML. I have tried many different outlets and changes to my html/js documents but still I am unable to figure out the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Below is my HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>title of my page</h1>
<div id="int">
<svg height="400" width="550">

</svg> 
</div>

<section id="p1">
<p>Paragraph 1 with some content</p>
</section>

<section id="p2">
<p>Another paragraph that pops up and has different content</p>
</section>

<div id="controls"><button id="continue">Continue the Story</button></div>




... and here is a copy of my .js document
to_p2 = function() {
  /* flip from p1 to p2 */
  $('#p1').hide()
  $('#p2').show()
  $('#continue').off()
  $('#continue').click(to_p3)

}
to_p3 = function() {
  /* flip from p2 to p3 */
  $('#p2').hide()
  $('#p3').show()
  $('#continue').off()
  $('#continue').click(to_p4)

} 

setup = function() {
  $('#continue').click(to_p2)
  $('section').hide()
  $('#p1').show() 
paper = Raphael('int', 400, 550)
    c = paper.circle(160, 120, 45)
    c = paper.circle(60, 100, 30)
    c = paper.circle(12, 60, 20)
    c.attr ({ 
    'fill': '#00f'
    }) 

}
jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```